# cat and mouse maze - How long does the mouse survive?

Tags: probability, random-walk

The diagram below shows the ﬂoor plan of a house with six rooms: in room 1 is a mouse which will change rooms every minute, ﬁrst moving at t = 1 and choosing a door to an adjoining room at random. In room 6 is a sleeping but hungry cat which will instantly wake if the mouse should enter. How long on average can we expect the mouse to survive?

[image: Maze]

I attempted this problem by setting up and solving simultaneous equations in terms of 5 $e_i$'s, the average survival time from room $i$. However, when I simulated this in Sage, I got a different answer.

Is the method below correct?

$$e_1=(e_4+1)/2+(e_2+1)/2$$$$e_3=e_2+1$$$$e_4=e_1+1$$$$e_2=(e_3+1)/3+(e_5+1)/3+(e_1+1)/3$$$$e_5=1/2+1/2(e_2+1)$$

Solving, $e_1=19$. Therefore the mouse survives 19 minutes on average.

In simulation, I got around 16 minutes average survival time.

```
def Mouse(): 
    counter=0
    room=1
    while room<6:
        if room==1:
            if randint(0,1)==0:
                room=4
            else:
                room=2
            counter=counter+1
        elif room==2:
            x=randint(0,2)
            if x==0:
                room=1
            if x==1:
                room=5
            if x==2:
                room=3
            counter=counter+1
        elif room==3:
            room=2
            counter=counter+1
        elif room==4:
            room=1
            counter+counter+1
        elif room==5:
            counter=counter+1
            if randint(0,1)==0:
                room=2
            else:
                room=6
    return(counter)
def MouseSim():
    total=0
    for i in range(10000):
        x=Mouse()
        total=total+x
    return N(total/10000)
MouseSim()
Out[19]:
15.9815000000000
```

Comment: My C++ simulation confirms that $19$ is the correct answer. You made a mistake :-)

Comment: TonyK's comment may be misleading: your equation is correct, your simulation is not. (check if the 4-5 or 3-6 is blocked in your simulation.

Comment: My Mathematica simulation also confirms that $19$ is the correct answer. Showing the code might help figure out what went wrong in your simulation.

Comment: @TonyK,@KingLogic,@Sangchul Lee. Thank you for the feedback. I have attached the code from my Sage simulation. Wasn't able to spot the mistake.

Comment: You have `counter+counter+1` instead of `counter=counter+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, and the answer is $19$. In your "room=4" case, you have a line `counter+counter+1` while it should say `counter=counter+1` instead. If you change this, the code returns an answer around $19$, like it should.

You can be less likely to make these sorts of issues if your line incrementing the counter is placed outside all of the if statements, since you increment the counter regardless of the value of `room`.